Difficulties upgrading old project to Android 14
I am experiencing tremendous difficulties upgrading a project to Android 14.
A little background into the project.
The project currently cannot be upgraded past Java 15 , API Level 33 and Gradle 7.0.2
This is the current setup for the application.
Updating Java to 17 gives me sun tools error. 
None of the recommendations for a fix works.
Subsequently, updating the API level to 34 throws an error as expected. Compiler does not compile against api 34, please set target api level to 31 or below.
Using the Android SDK Upgrade Assistant 
shows me errors on files I cannot edit as they are generated files.
Furthermore the app still employs kotlin-android-extensions, which is now deprecated.
Removing this and adding in the parcelize, throws me over 1700 errors to fix which is expected as the entire app uses synthetic bindings. .
My question is.
What is the BEST path forward and with least resistance to update to Android 14 and target api level 34 minimum given all of the project difficulties.
Am I forced to FIRST fix all of the 1700+ errors before I am able to move forward with upgrading SDK and Java?
Is there a better way forward?

Please provide all text that can be copied as text not as a screenshot.

Given that kotlin-android-extensions has been deprecated for a while: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated you should probably roll back to a working contemporary version and handle those issues before attempting to advance the targetAPI.
